# Google Blobstore being blocked on some networks

Tags: google-app-engine

I am getting reports that images we are serving from Google Blobstore (ggpht.com) are being blocked on some networks. Does anyone have a suggestion on how we can avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

[Is this the answer?](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/PicasaSomethingBroken/slUTFEuVSdk)

Undoing "Block Images from Ih6.ggpht.com"